# How to get the parent of a non-hierarchical custom post type being edited in Gutenberg

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, block-editor, hierarchical

It's a common practice to use the `post_parent` property in the `WP_Post` class to create 1-to-n relationships between different custom post types.

In an plugin I'm developing, I added a `SelectControl` to the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` to be able to set the id of a related custom post type in another custom post type. According to the docs, I should use `getEditedPostAttribute` to retrieve the current "parent" (the id of the related custom post type) of the custom post type being edited:

```
select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'parent' )
```

But, for some reason, I'm getting an `undefined` value even though the `post_parent` property is set. A custom meta box in the classic editor shows it correctly.

If I set the `hierarchical` property in the custom post type to `true`, the selector works and I get the correct value. Is this by design? Or are we forced to use a custom meta field to store this data, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the correct Gutenberg/JS code, but it's a limitation in the REST API which exposes the `parent` field only for hierarchical post types like `page`. But you can force the field to appear in the REST API responses via [`register_rest_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) — example for a `my_cpt` post type:

```php
register_rest_field( 'my_cpt', 'parent', array(
    'schema' => array(
        'description' => __( 'The ID for the parent of the post.' ),
        'type'        => 'integer',
        'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit' ),
    ),
) );
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`rest_prepare_<post type>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/) to just add the `parent` in the response:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_my_cpt', function ( $response, $post ) {
    $data = $response->get_data();
    $data['parent'] = $post->post_parent;
    $response->set_data( $data );

    return $response;
}, 10, 2 );
```

But if you want to allow editing the parent via the REST API, then the first option is preferred.

Comment: Using your first method, it works, but a notice is thrown too: PHP Notice:  WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_item_schema was called incorrectly. Please use register_rest_field to add new schema properties. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 5.4.0.)

Comment: Hi. Sorry about that.. :p I've updated the code.